# 4K resolution videos lag

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, vlc, acer, 4k-monitor

I have Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.2 LTS installed on an Acer F15 F5-573-70EB[Here] laptop with an i7 CPU, NVIDIA GTX 950m GPU, and 16GB RAM. I connect it to a Philips 4K HDR TV.

Before installing NVIDIA's drivers, full HD worked fine on the integrated Intel 620 GPU. Yet choosing 4k resolution with 200% scaling option, playback became laggy, non smooth, both in browser and VLC. I reverted back to 1080P which is fine.

After installing NVIDIA drivers from within Ubuntu updates and software, I get the same results.

How should I approach solving this?

Comment: I edited for better info

Comment: Try gst-play-1.0, ffplay -loglevel 16, SMPlayer, and MPV.